# Defining scale3d origin with css3

Tags: css

I've been working on creating an animating bar graph using css3. It's been working well for the sides of the bars, but the top and bottoms of the bars have been problematic.

I've been scaling the sides just by altering their css 'height' property via jQuery, but I realize that's not the best way to do it. I've tried using scale3d(), but it always scales the object from what seems to be the center of the object. I need it to scale the object from the bottom of the cube. Here's the css I've got so far (using stylus)

```
#barTwo
#barOne
#barThree
#barFour
    position relative
    -webkit-transition -webkit-transform 2s linear
    -webkit-transform-style preserve-3d
    height 400px
    width 100px
    float left
    margin-left 100px

.face
    position absolute
    height 360px
    width 80px
    padding 20px
    background-color rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3)
    bottom 0px
    left 0px
    -webkit-transition 10000ms all

.one /* top */
    -webkit-transform rotateX(90deg) translateZ(340px)
    height 80px     
    background-color rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.9)
    display none

.two /* front */
    -webkit-transform translateZ(60px)
    background-color rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7)

.three /* right */
    -webkit-transform rotateY(90deg) translateZ(60px)
    background-color rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.6)

.four /* back */
    -webkit-transform rotateY(180deg) translateZ(60px)
    background-color rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7)

.five /* left */
    -webkit-transform rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(60px)
    background-color rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8)

.six /* bottom */
    -webkit-transform rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(60px) rotate(180deg)
    background-color rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.9)
    height 80px
    display none
```

Draws a great rectangle, but scaling them 'upwards' has been eluding me.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `*-transform-origin` property. Its default value is 50%, 50%. If you want things to scale upwards then 50%, 100% is what you're looking for (it sets the origin at the bottom of the element.)

Comment: I have no idea why that was so difficult for me to find. Thank you very much.